# Google Cloud Storage - Upload Large File (4GB)

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have the following script which works with small files, however fails when I try a huge file (4GB):

```
<?php

  require 'vendor/autoload.php';

  use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

  $storage = new StorageClient([
      'keyFilePath' => 'keyfile.json',
      'projectId' => 'storage-123456'
  ]);

  $bucket = $storage->bucket('my-bucket');

  $options = [
      'resumable' => true,
        'chunkSize' => 200000,
        'predefinedAcl' => 'publicRead'
  ];

  // Upload a file to the bucket.
  $bucket->upload(
      fopen('data/file.imgc', 'r'),
      $options
  );

?>
```

The error I receive is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\GoogleException' with message 'Upload failed. Please use this URI to resume your upload:
```

Any ideas how to upload a large file?

http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.61.0/storage/bucket?method=upload

I've also tried the getResumableUploader():

```
$uploader = $bucket->getResumableUploader(fopen('data/file.imgc', 'r'), [
  'name' => 'file.imgc'
]);

try {
  $object = $uploader->upload();
} catch (GoogleException $ex) {
  $resumeUri = $uploader->getResumeUri();
  $object = $uploader->resume($resumeUri);
}
```

When navigating to the resume URI it returns "Method Not Allowed"

Comment: This can be done by uploading the files in chunks by [this package](https://github.com/pionl/laravel-chunk-upload). Example project - https://github.com/pionl/laravel-chunk-upload-example

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t used this API, but I don’t think you’re supposed to just open a massive file into memory and then stuff it into this single request. You’re requesting a resumable operation, so read small portions of the file, like a couple MB at a time, and loop through it, until you have uploaded all parts of it.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that stands out as an issue, potentially, is the chosen chunkSize of 200000. Per the documentation, the chunkSize must be provided as multiples of 262144.

Also, when dealing with large files, I would highly recommend using[`Bucket::getResumableUploader()`](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.63.0/storage/bucket?method=getResumableUploader). It will help give you better control over the upload process and you should find it will be more reliable :). There is a code snippet in the link I shared that should help get you started.

Comment: Hi David, I've tried getResumableUploader() and get the following response: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\GoogleException' with message 'Upload failed. Please use this URI to resume your upload: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/jobsystem/o?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=AEnB2UpSE4ZNrO3qk06BgmFVOUUXlbEPgTxO84DCGOlTspm4Mg-465htc5aPbHtYK89Qbavkgz_6Nhfe1-_AG2iDQhRobklG0Q' in C:\wamp64\www\google-cloud-php\Storage\vendor\google\cloud-core\src\Upload\ResumableUploader.php on line 170`

The link returns **Method Not Allowed**, any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Do you still get an issue when setting the chunkSize to 262144?

Comment: Where in the docs does it say it must be a multiple of 262144 @davids?  I can't find it.  I've used a lot of different chunk sizes that are not a multiple and haven't seen any issues.